# Codepush not working for all android users

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, code-push

Hey guys I'm using Microsoft's CodePush with an Ionic app ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/code-push/ ).

It works perfectly for our iOS users and most of our Android users, however we are getting a large amount of reports from Android users that it's not working. They're saying that it's freezing on the checking for updates screen.

I can't seem to find any consistency among the users that are reporting this. I've been asking about their version of Android, which phone they have and how much available storage they have. All of the Android test devices I have work fine with it so I'm not really sure where to go from here.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has any experience in this and might know where to point me to look into this deeper. Thanks!

Comment: So it's looking like it's only android version 8.0+ that is experiencing this problem....

Comment: Another update: I went out and bought a cheap android phone with version 8.0 and codepush is giving the following error: [CodePush] Could not get binary hash.Error: Could not get binary hash.

Comment: Nevermind the last comment - it throws that error on my other Android on 6.0 as well but it works on that phone so I don't think that's part of the issue..

Comment: Looking into this further it seems that after I do a codepush update on my Android 8.0 phone, this.codePush.checkForUpdate().then( (remotePackage) => {  THIS NEVER HAPPENS });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working by doing the following:

1) Follow @BRass's post and ensure that webview is on version 1.2.1

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
ionic cordova platform add android
```

2) Go to your index.html and add

```
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
```

directly before

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And VOILA it works!

Comment: Note: Since this post I found that if you are not using cordova android version 7.x.x, Codepush may not work on all versions of android. Make sure your cordova android version is up to date!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some folks are seeing issues with code push and some recent ionic webview releases.  You may want to peek at that and see if it's related:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/451

Comment: Thanks for the response - it looks like their problem is the new version of webview.  They're saying the last working version was 1.2.1, however I'm on version 1.1.16 of webview. This problem has been happening for a long time for us so I don't think it's related - it's just becoming more prevalent now because our user base is increasing.